# SQL ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered

Tags: sql, create-table

I cannot understand what is the issue here , i received:

> ERROR 42X01 Syntax error: Encountered

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE coupon40 (id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(25), start_date DATE,"
+ " end_date DATE,"
+ "amount INTEGER,  type ENUM ('Food', 'Electric', 'Traveling', 'Entertainment', 'Sport'), "
+ "message VARCHAR(25), price DOUBLE PRECISION, image VARCHAR(25)";
```

Comment: Can you please post the whole error?

Comment: Missing closing parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close the brackets.

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE coupon40 (id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(25), start_date DATE,"
+ " end_date DATE,"
+ "amount INTEGER,  type ENUM ('Food', 'Electric', 'Traveling', 'Entertainment', 'Sport'), "
+ "message VARCHAR(25), price DOUBLE PRECISION, image VARCHAR(25))";
```

Comment: thank you , but what about this one ?

String sql = "CREATE TABLE coupon53 (id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(25), start_date DATE,"

+ " end_date DATE, amount INT, type ENUM ('Food', 'Electric', 'Travelling', 'Entertainment', 'Sport'))";